# Notifications in servicestack

Tags: notifications, servicestack

After certain actions (say a PUT or a DELETE) in my services, I will like to send a notification to a user or to a group of users, this is done before send the response of the action.

My way to implement notifications is quite simple, I have an interface:

```
public Interface INotification{
    void send(string mail, string content);
    void send(Group group, string content);
}
```

that represents every type of notification. I inject the types of notifications that are used in a given service but I don't see this as an optimal solution. Is there a better way to accomplish this? are any frameworks that integrates easily with ServiceStack that help me achieve this?

Another problem from my point of view is loading a template, this is done every time I send the notification. I don't like this approach since I assume that this is not optimal. (but this is a different problem)

Thanks for all the help you can provide me.

Answer (score 1):

I am considering adding EventStore to my app to handle a similar scenario, with the added requirement of an auditable history of object changes:

https://github.com/joliver/EventStore

I've not tried it out yet.

Comment: I will take a look, this might be what I need, Thanks for sharing I will update with my progress soon.